# Where can I get durable bows?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I am playing BOTW and and beat one divine beast so far. Now I am going to divine beast vah rudania. However, all my bows broke! So, I am looking for good durable bows. I want to go to the Gerudo tower NW to get the golden bow. I know the knight's bow I can get this in the divine beast vah rudania. Where can I get more durable bows? I want to get like 3 more if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are many many places you can find bows in this game.

- If you have the money, ancient parts, and have completed the quest Robbie's Research, you can buy the Ancient Bow from Cherry at the Akkala Ancient Tech Lab. [This is considered one of the most, if not the most, durable bows in the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307117/how-durable-are-the-ancient-weapons-cherry-makes/307156#307156).
- Another reliable source of bow's that I found was Hinoxes. These lovely things have 3 weapons around their necklace and one of them is always a bow.
- Find monster towers (those wooden platform tower things) and kill em all. Usually one or more will have a bow you can use.
- Once you start getting ambushed by the Yiga clan, the weaker ones will drop a [Duplex bow](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Duplex_Bow) once dispatched.

Answer (score 24):

Time to go [Lynel](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Lynel) hunting!!

Lynel's have a [super cool bow](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Lynel_Bow) in this game that--for the price of one arrow--will shoot three shots at once! Most Lynels carry this awesome bow on their back and will drop it when killed. Not to mention, they also drop a pretty beefy weapon and sometimes a very nice shield!

The only downside here is the fight itself. Lynels have a crazy amount of health, so fighting them will take some time and will usually break a weapon or two of yours. After I finish a dungeon or am in between tasks in BotW, I'll collect up a bunch of subpar weapons and go sacrifice them into a lynel for their bow, melee weapon and shield. Not to mention, their guts and horns are useful for crafting or selling!

The Lynels in the game can be found in these locations (with the weapons listed by letter):

[image]

I've taken this image from [this enlightening Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/87num5) that also includes a little more information in text form in the comments.

If you have trouble defeating them, there are [a plethora of online guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=breath+of+the+wild+lynel+guide) for how to handle them (even [one right here on Arqade!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/302944/222207)). Once you get the timing down to flurry rush their attacks, they get a lot easier!

Comment: "Other" meaning Bomb Arrows. Lol

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a durable bow, I would definitely suggest beating ganon (dark beast ganon is optional) and getting the Bow of Light. If you don’t have all the divine beasts though then I would definitely suggest going through Divine Beast Vah Medoh.

Some people don’t know this, but once you beat it and go to the Elder in Rito Village, he will give you the Great Eagle Bow which is three arrows at once and only cost one arrow per shot.

But remember, for every divine beast, there will be a boss battle with a minor Gannon form such as wind blight Gannon, fire blight Gannon, thunder blight Gannon, and water blight Gannon.

But honestly other than that I would definitely suggest the ancient Bow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure unless you want to do a glitch, getting the light bow is impossible. After you defeat dark beast gannon, you go to your last save outside of hyrule castle.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just farm Lyenls. If you kill the white maned, silver, and gold ones(master mode), they can give you 32x3 bows (32 damage with 3 arrows) If you're lucky, you can get 32x5 bows! I just look down/fly to them and headshot them. They will stagger, so pull out your best weapon(it won't lose durability) and mount it to get on the Lynel. continue whacking and it'll fling you off. (This will cost stamina so be prepared) Then when you get the chance, stasis it and shoot it. this will stun them, and after it shakes it's head, headshot it and mount it. continue for a little bit and you will get AWESOME gear. This will only use arrows and bow durability. Just use the other people's guides to get 1 or 2 bows and follow this strategy. EDIT: Lynels will only drop shock, fire, ice, bomb, but no normal arrows. after farming Lynels for a long time, I just use shock arrows for normal arrows. I just have too much. (Lynels drop shock arrows most often)

Answer (score 0):

In Hyrule Castle there's a Knight's Bow right away if you follow the right guide. Sit by a fire until a blood moon and it will respawn. This is my best way.